# Function statement in object declaration in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var argument1 = {
    myvar : "12",
    mymethod : function(test) { return something; } // this line here
}
```

Is this a function statement or a function expression? And why can't I write something like this:

```
var argument1 = {
    myvar : "12",
    function f(test) { return something; }
}
```

but I can write this:

```
function func() {
    myvar : "12",
    function b(test) { return something; }
}
```

They are both objects. How can the former give error and the latter is fine?

Comment: What syntax would you use to call/invoke the former across argument1? - It's anonymous.

Comment: The latter gives no error either?  Not even on that `myvar` line?  Neither of the latter two examples look right to me, only the very first one.  In the first example you define an object, and one of the properties on that object is a function.  What are you trying to change about that and why?

Comment: No, no errors. It works fine. Actually that line wasn't intended to be there, I've left it accidentally when I copy-pasted from the above code. My intention was the function b only. Now I see that I can write this too. Any explanation on this additional problem? Thanks.

Comment: Protip: Paste your code snippet(s) into http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html and examine the tree view. It will tell you _exactly_ what your code means at the structural level. Plus you can learn about labelled statements, function declarations, sequence expressions, etc.

Comment: Also, may I ask if you are using an old, pre-ES2015, version of JavaScript? Each of your examples is perfectly fine and does give any compile time error. When you say "how come the former give error and the latter is fine?", what error are you referring to? There is no error in modern JavaScript, but there would be an error in old JavaScript.

Comment: There was a typo in the second snipped. I added the identifier `f`. The question is how I can do the declaration in the third and not in the second snippet.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are defining a variable that holds an object. That object has a key `mymethod` that has a function assigned to it. It is indeed an anonymous function expression. You could do something like `argument1.mymethod('omg')`
2. This one again is a variable being assigned an object. However this object is probably not what you expect. In ES6 this will create an object with a property `function` that has the anonymous function assigned to it. In ES5 this will fail with a syntax error. e.g., `argument1.function('yessss')`.
3. This is a function declaration. When executed, the function declares a label (rare in js) named myvar then evaluates the expression `"12"`, tosses the result and then declares a function named b. This function will return undefined when executed. The `,` operator is fun and labels are funner.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first snippet: `function(x) { ... }` returns an *anonymous function*.

Regarding your second snippet: you can do it like this:

```
var argument1 = {
    myvar: "12",
    test() { return something; }
};
```

Regarding your third snippet, the syntax `name: expr` declares a label called `name`, instead of an object property. (This is a common source of confusion.)

The `,` operator outside of a function evaluates both of its arguments and returns the second. So your third snippet labels a line `myvar`, then evaluates the string `"12"` and discards it, then declares a function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have a question. Why I can't write `var ob = {function f(){}` but I can write `function f(){function b(){}}`. What is the difference here when `ob` and `f` are both objects? And also, the `test` function in your example returns anonymous function too right?

Comment: @LearningMath You can give a name to an anonymous function, like `var obj = function f() {};`, which causes both `obj` and `f` to be defined. Or, you can not give a name, like `obj = function() {};`, which causes only `obj` to be defined. The `var object = {f() { }};` is special syntax.